# SAP Jar not getting recognized in Eclipse

Tags: java, jco

My java program which I created could not recognize `SAPJCO3.jar` which is already in the system class path and included in eclipse/project with buildpath option available in Eclipse.

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: com.sap.conn.jco.AbapException
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/conn/jco/AbapException

If I just remove `AbapException`  from my program and give normal Java exception , it throws error on the next JCo class. The same program works good in NETBEANS which I used for testing. Since my actual project was developed in Eclipse I need the program to run in Eclipse.
Can any one help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the property to your windows "System variables"/"Environment variables".

Variable Name: java.library.path
Variable Value: C:/SAPJCo

This will work for Eclise.

Good Luck!!